# Put a slash through a word

Tags: text-decorations, strikeout, cancel

I would like to write a word with a slash through it, using LaTeX (in text, not in math mode). That is, I want a line from the lower-left corner of the word through the upper-right. Is there a nice way to do this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "lower-left" corner?  Should the line start at the baseline, in the lower left corner of the bounding box of the word, or somewhere else?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Load the [`cancel`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cancel) package and use `\cancel{word}`. Most of the commands from the package work in both math and text modes.

Comment: Thanks! It's not quite perfect; it would be nice if the line were thicker if the word is in a larger font, which doesn't seem to be the case. But it might suffice.

Answer (score 12):

Following frabjous' advice, I seem to have discovered a bug in the `cancel` package: Cancelling at the start of a paragraph only works if you add `\leavevmode`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cancel}

\begin{document}

Some text.

% \cancel{Some text.}% Doesn't work
\leavevmode\cancel{Some text.}% Works

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

You might like to try the [`ulem`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/ulem.html) package and use the command `\sout{word}` to strikeout a word.

Comment: I agree that `ulem` can be very useful but do watch out - it hijacks `\emph`, typesetting emphasised text in underline. The fix is very simple, after loading, issue `\normalem` to restore `\emph` back to its original meaning.

Comment: Use `\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}` to avoid the problem mentioned by Geoffrey.

Answer (score 9):

Another possibility with tikz.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\newcommand*\cancel[2][thin]{\tikz[baseline] \node [strike out,draw,anchor=text,inner sep=0pt,text=black,#1]{#2};}  

\begin{document}   

First \cancel{word} canceled, second  \cancel[thick,draw=red]{attempt}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `strike out` from the `shapes.misc` library in TikZ. See the sample code below:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\newcommand{\strikeout}[1]{%
\tikz[baseline, inner sep=0.5pt] \node [strike out,draw=OrangeRed,anchor=text]{#1};}
\begin{document}
Sample text \strikeout{strike} out.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes you need `\tikz[baseline] ` and to add an optional argument

Comment: @Altermundus I had it but I removed it. Don't remember why I did.