# How to strike through obliquely, e.g. to indicate cancellation?

Tags: text-decorations, strikeout, cancel

How can I strike through an expression (e.g. "2x") obliquely, e.g. from bottom left to top right, so as to indicate cancellation? With the `\sout` command from the `ulem` package, I can only strike horizontally.

Comment: near duplicate to [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4465/put-a-slash-through-a-word](putting a slash through a word), although that doesn't have such nice example images.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

The [`cancel`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cancel) package seems to do exactly what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cancel}

\begin{document}

\( \cancel{2x} \)

\( \cancel{1234567890} \)

\end{document}
```

[image: cancelled items]

If you're not satisfied with how the cancellation starts below the *1* and ends above the *0*, have a look at [Diagonal strikeout starting too low and ending too high](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20643/diagonal-strikeout-starting-too-low-and-ending-too-high).