# Latin Extended: Latin Capital Letter A With Stroke

Tags: code

Latin Capital Letter O with Stroke is working but how about if I'm using another Letter like A, B, C to Z.

```
\documentclass{article}

 \begin{document}
 {\O} %replacing the O with different letter is not working {\A} or {\Z}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean? Please add some code (a minimal working example)

Comment: @Guido: sample code added

Comment: Oslash is a character in many european alphabets (mostly from noreh Europe). If you want to put a slash over other letters you have to use different techniques. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40253/16895

Comment: What kind is the stroke? In `\O` it the Unicode letter `U+00D8` (Latin Capital Letter D), whereas the stroking by package `\cancel` has a different purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Unicode lists the following characters:

Ø U+00D8 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH STROKE
ø U+00F8 LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH STROKE
Đ U+0110 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER D WITH STROKE
đ U+0111 LATIN SMALL LETTER D WITH STROKE
Ħ U+0126 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER H WITH STROKE
ħ U+0127 LATIN SMALL LETTER H WITH STROKE
Ł U+0141 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L WITH STROKE
ł U+0142 LATIN SMALL LETTER L WITH STROKE
Ŧ U+0166 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T WITH STROKE
ŧ U+0167 LATIN SMALL LETTER T WITH STROKE
ƀ U+0180 LATIN SMALL LETTER B WITH STROKE
Ɨ U+0197 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH STROKE
ƛ U+019B LATIN SMALL LETTER LAMBDA WITH STROKE
Ƶ U+01B5 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z WITH STROKE
ƶ U+01B6 LATIN SMALL LETTER Z WITH STROKE
Ǥ U+01E4 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER G WITH STROKE
ǥ U+01E5 LATIN SMALL LETTER G WITH STROKE
Ⱥ U+023A LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH STROKE
Ȼ U+023B LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C WITH STROKE
ȼ U+023C LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH STROKE
Ƀ U+0243 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER B WITH STROKE
Ɇ U+0246 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E WITH STROKE
ɇ U+0247 LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH STROKE
Ɉ U+0248 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER J WITH STROKE
ɉ U+0249 LATIN SMALL LETTER J WITH STROKE
Ɍ U+024C LATIN CAPITAL LETTER R WITH STROKE
ɍ U+024D LATIN SMALL LETTER R WITH STROKE
Ɏ U+024E LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Y WITH STROKE
ɏ U+024F LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH STROKE
ɨ U+0268 LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH STROKE

Of these, only Ø, ø, Đ, đ, Ł, ł are directly supported in T1 encoding, while some others are supported in T3 (IPA) and T4 (African languages). The commands that produce the T1 supported ones are

```
\O \o \DJ \dj \L \l
```

If you need others you have to emulate them with superimposing a bar (or some other trick).