# Printing a cross across another symbol

Tags: math-mode

Is there any command or macro for printing a character with a cross over it?

Comment: Are you referring to something like cancelling? As in [How to strike through obliquely, e.g. to indicate cancellation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40253/5764)

Comment: I need a double stroke, like a big X across a C.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `tikz` anything is possible if you are determined.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\newcommand*{\mycancel}[2][draw]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[cross out,inner sep=0.5pt,outer sep=0pt,#1]{#2};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
  \mycancel[draw=red]{C} \mycancel{$\alpha$}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But there is already a package for it and you can use it in math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cancel,color,amsmath}

\begin{document}
  $\xcancel{C}$

  \renewcommand{\CancelColor}{\color{red}}
  $\xcancel{C}$

  $\xcancel{\text{C}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]