# How to strikethrough diagonally, from left top to right bottom?

Tags: strikeout

While [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40253/how-to-strike-through-obliquely-e-g-to-indicate-cancellation) already has a diagonal strikethrough solution with `\cancel`, this is actually, in a matrix terminology meaning, "anti diagonal", i.e. from lower left to upper right. What I want here is **from upper left to lower right strikethrough**.

A command in existed package is prefered, otherwise, a solution with minimal user-definition is prefered. Because I hope to work in markdown :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you type `texdoc cancel` at a command prompt to open the package's user guide, you can't miss the following information on page 1:

[image]

I'd thus say that the command you're looking for is called `\bcancel`.

Oh, all three commands work in both math mode and text mode.