# I want to indicate that two items cancel each other out using some kind of strike through

Tags: stacking-symbols

The subject line just about says it. If I have ab/b I want to indicate that the b's cancel. On a board I would simply strike them through. How to I do the same in LaTex? I've tagged this as stacking-symbols as I'm guessing that's like the trick but I can't figure out which symbol and how to stack it.

Comment: You can do it with the `cancel` package.

Comment: Shiny! Thanks @Bernard.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.

Comment: @Bernard Please turn that into an answer.

Comment: @Stephen; You're right, it would be helpful also to others. 'Tis  done.

Comment: Maybe same question as [text decorations - How to strike through obliquely, e.g. to indicate cancellation? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40253/how-to-strike-through-obliquely-e-g-to-indicate-cancellation), or one of the many questions linked from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how to do it with `cancel`:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{cancel, amsmath}

    \begin{document}

        \[ \frac{a\cancel{b}}{\cancel{b}} = a \]%

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, I will mention the `\not` command. It does not depend on any package, but the strike-through is not always very nice.

It is usually used for operators instead of symbols, so `\not\sim`, `\not\cong`, `\not\equiv` etc.

It can also be used for other symbols, such as `\not\exists`, but the results are usually unsatisfactory. In this specific case, `\nexists` from `amsmath` package is better.

For example, consider the following code

```
\begin{document}
$$\not\sim\ \not\cong\ \not\equiv\ \not\exists$$
$${\displaystyle\frac{a\not b}{\not b}}\ 
{\textstyle \frac{a\not b}{\not b}}\ 
{\scriptstyle\frac{a\not b}{\not b}}$$
\end{document}
```

It produces the following output: [image: Latex Not example output]

You can see that the strike-through  in the fractions makes the whitespace around the `b` ugly in the `\displaystyle` example, and in the other examples the strikethrough is not through the middle of the `b`.

For your specific case, the `cancel` package mentioned above is much better, but in other cases the `\not` command might help.

Comment: Thanks for the followup. I hadn't realized \not could be used with a variety of elements.