# Cancelling in a Fraction

Tags: fractions, cancel

I am trying to create a step-by-step solution sheet for my homework and have discovered that I need to use "cancel" things in a fraction.  For example, like in the following picture

[image]

I would like to draw lines through the term `b-4`.

Comment: `\cancelto` from `\usepackage{cancel}` will do this.

Comment: See [How to strike through obliquely, e.g. to indicate cancellation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40253/5764) and/or [Put a slash through a word](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4465/5764) (possible duplicates). Use [`cancel`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cancel)'s `\bcancel`.